# Firebase: watch for reconnect after permission_denied

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I've built an application that allows a user to stream their application state to other users. The streamer can dictate whether or not the stream is public. If the stream is public, there's a flag set in Firebase that lets others access it by getting the URL to the object (otherwise, they get `permission_denied`).

This flag can be changed while the broadcast is going on. If it is, it forcibly disconnects all clients watching the broadcast. That part makes sense. What I can't seem to figure out is how to watch for a reconnect, in case it goes public again. There doesn't seem to be anything in the docs about recovering or watching for reconnection from this particular state. The only thing a client can do is hit F5 a lot, which is not a good solution if they've been given a link to the broadcast and want to go there early.

So, my question: Is it possible to watch for a reconnection to a Firebase object even if you've received `permission_denied`? If so, how?

Or maybe it's better to always allow permission, but conceal the data inside the object until it's ready (ie, allow a read on the object, but none of its properties)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,   better give access to the object's `metadata`, but limit the access to the `content` (via fb permissions).     Then, on your client-side, you only watch the `metadata` for changes.   this would also be more precise, and less traffic.

Comment: Sounds OK to me. Thanks for confirming that.